# Concatenating with the aggregate function in R

Tags: r, aggregate

I've obtained a datased, which needs to be concatenated/aggregated by specific criteria. I know how to do this for numeric variables, but this time, I need to compute something from string vectors, for example i have:

```
V1 V2
1 YYY
1 MMMMMM
1 UUUU
2 YY
2 UUU
.
.
.
```

I am trying to compute the MU % on specific V1, so my result set would look something like:

```
V1 V2
1  75%
2  60%
```

I've been fiddling around with the aggregate function, but I cannot get it to at least paste join all data from V1, so

```
aggregate(V1~V2, data=x,FUN=paste(x))
```

obviously doesn't work for me.

Comment: What do you mean by MU %? I'm not clear on what you're trying to do.

Comment: Percentage of M and U characters amongst all characters occuring in specific V1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a `dplyr` and `stringr` solution

```
## Create the sample data
dat <- read.table(text = "V1 V2
1 YYY
1 MMMMMM
1 UUUU
2 YY
2 UUU", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

## Load the packages
library("dplyr")
library("stringr")
```

For each group in `V1`, calculate the number of M's & U's out of the total number of characters:

```
dat %>%
  group_by(V1) %>%
  summarize(V2 = sum(str_count(V2, "M|U")) / sum(nchar(V2)))

## Source: local data frame [2 x 2]

##      V1        V2
##   (int)     (dbl)
## 1     1 0.7692308
## 2     2 0.6000000
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way straight from the original dataset:

```
library(stringi)
stack(
tapply(d$V2, d$V1, 
  function(ii) sum(stri_count_regex(ii, "M|U")) / 
               sum(stri_count_regex(ii, "."))))
#     values ind
#1 0.7692308   1
#2 0.6000000   2
```

---

To use the aggregate statement you just need a few changes:

```
d2 <- aggregate(V2 ~ V1, data=d, function(ii) paste0(ii, collapse="")) 

# no packages used in this solution:
d2$V2 <- 
  sapply(
    strsplit(d2$V2, "", perl=TRUE),
    function(ii) sum(grepl("M|U", ii))/length(ii))
#  V1        V2
#1  1 0.7692308
#2  2 0.6000000
```

Or with the `stri_count` function from the `stringi` package, there's a nice shorter option:

```
d2 <- aggregate(V2~V1, data=d, function(ii) paste0(ii, collapse="")) 

library(stringi)
d2$V2 <- stri_count_regex(d2$V2, "M|U") / nchar(d2$V2)
#  V1        V2
#1  1 0.7692308
#2  2 0.6000000
```

Comment: Another base only option `f <- function(x) sum(attr(regexpr("M*|U*", x), "match.length"))/sum(nchar(x)) ; aggregate(V2 ~ V1, dat, f)`

Answer (score 0):

An option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)[, list(V2=sum(nchar(V2)-nchar(gsub("M|U", "", 
                         V2)))/sum(nchar(V2))), V1]
#   V1        V2
#1:  1 0.7692308
#2:  2 0.6000000
```